# Migrations in Sequelize in my own folder structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am new to `Sequelize` and my current project requires me to use it with migrations. I am familiar with migrations what they do and how. 
I am coming from `Django` background where each sub app has modals, views, apis, urls and migrations in the same folder. i like the structure and want to keep the same in my nodejs app. i am trying to put a feature at one place. it makes more sense to me.

my structure

```
|---api
     |---user
     |    |--- api.js
     |    |--- utils.js
     |    |--- models.js
     |    |--- index.js
     |    |--- migrations
     |            |--- xxx123-migration.js
     |            |--- xxx1235-migration.js
     |---payment
          |--- api.js
          |--- utils.js
          |--- models.js
          |--- index.js
          |--- migrations
                  |--- xxx123-migration.js
                  |--- xxx1235-migration.js
```

now my problem is that i dont know how to m make `Sequelize-cli` point to my folders and look for migrations to generate and run.

`Sequelize-cli` generates their own folders for models, config, seeds etc. which I don't want to follow.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 21):

**EDIT:**

after your updated structure , it is not possible to use .sequelizerc file to do so, because it doesn't support multiple migration folder.

You need to create `.sequelizerc` file at project root to override the default path. see [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#the-sequelizerc-file)

If I assume `api` is the first folder inside project root from your folder structure , the models are in `api/user` and migrations are in `api/user/migrations`.  The following should work:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('CONFIGPATHHERE', 'sequelize.js'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('api/user', 'sequelize'),
  'migrations-path': path.resolve('api/user', 'migrations')
}
```

make sure you specify sequelize config path.

Comment: what if have many folders like user.. ex inside my api i have `user`, `auth`, `payment`, etc. how can i point to all folders inside api ?

Comment: @hannadrehman sry I don't think its possible to do so with sequelize, you might need https://github.com/sequelize/umzug, even with `umzug` i'm not sure its possible to do multiple model folders and then migration folder inside models folders.

Comment: i might be wrong. but it makes sense to keep migration in the same folder as in models. your answer works only if i have one folder inside api. what do you think is the best way to organise this kinda of project ? any leads is much appriciated @feiiiiii

Comment: @hannadrehman I usually put migration folder under `db` folder at the root level, and models folder on same level with my `controller` folder. There is no best way, it is your personal choice, but `sequelize-cli` has limitations, its just the structure you want, currently is not very convenient  to go with.

Comment: is there any other ORM that can support my way of structure. putting one feature in one folder seems more convenient to me. if there is no way then i will have to do it your suggested way only

Comment: @hannadrehman I have only used sequelize for traditional db. I think you might need to ask this question in https://dba.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0):

based on issues [\https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/28][1](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/28) we can add flag in model:generate command

(example) : npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name modelName --models-path .\some\  --attributes name:string

make sure models properly imported in models/index.js file